# How to fix "error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I'd like to use IBM's Watson API SpeechToText on Unity (ver.2018.4.13).
First, I'm reading https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/blob/master/README.md and tried to install but console said

> Assets\unity-sdk-core-1.2.0\Utilities\CredentialUtils.cs(268,70):warning CS0618: 'Credential.ApiKey' is obsolete: 'Authentication using legacy apikey is deprecated. Please authenticate using TokenOptions.'
>
> Assets\unity-sdk-core-1.2.0\Connection\RESTConnector.cs(664,24): error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'

and

> Assets\unity-sdk-core-1.2.0\Authentication\CloudPakForData\CloudPakForDataAuthenticator.cs(35,31): warning CS0414: The field 'CloudPakForDataAuthenticator.UrlSuffix' is assigned but its value is never used

How can I solve these error and warnings.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you are not using the latest Unity SDK or core. Please download the latest from https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/releases and https://github.com/IBM/unity-sdk-core/releases

Also please set your API Compatibility Level to .NET 4.x

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk#configuring-unity

Comment: For me, I was working on a hobby project with a VS extension and used dynamic objects and got this error. I needed latest "Microsoft.Csharp" nuget package.